# Syntax section of CBH

Tags: powershell

The syntax section of the comment-based-help documentation of my scripts looks like this

```
SYNTAX
C:\scripts\forms_invoke.ps1 [[-proc_type] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

But the -proc_type parameter can only be one of three distinct values. The parameter and description sections explain this. How do I change the CBH to display this information in the SYNTAX section?

Comment: Does the [about_Comment_Based_Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help) help topic say that this is possible?

Comment: It doesn't. And the other two sections do document the requirement. I was just hoping to get something more direct.

Comment: Can you please include how you define the parameters?

Comment: The latest version of the parameter definition is:
`Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="A process type of distribute, import or purge is required!")]
 [ValidateSet("distribute", "import", "purge")]
 [string]$proc_type
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [ValidateSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#validateset-attribute) attribute at the specific parameter. The Powershell tab completions will suggest only supported values from the set.

```
Function test-docu{
[cmdletbinding()] 
Param(
   [ValidateSet ("a", "b")] 
    $p1
 ) 
}

Get-Help Test-docu
```

Output:

```
NAME
test-docu

 SYNTAX
     test-docu [[-p1] {a | b}]      
 [<CommonParameters>]
```

You can also test it [online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3600L7kkMz9PoSS1uEQ3JT@5tJpLAQiik3NTclJLkjLzUjLz0jU0YxXAwgGJRYm5GmAmSFFYYk5mSmJJanBqiYKGUqKSjoJSkhJMLQioFBiC2JoKXLVcXO6pJboeqTkFCiEwu7i4/v8HAA).

Comment: Keep in mind that above only applies to a function, not to script, which is important in that case (as OP is using script in the question).

Comment: Thought it should also work for a script, since `ValidateSet` is a parameter attribute, and not a function one.

Comment: I tried that yesterday but wasn't able to achieve this for script (while it works for function without any issue).

Comment: Yes, this is a PowerShell script that will be called by a scheduling tool.